# Adding a timestamp to a pcollection

Tags: apache-beam

I'm pretty new to Beam and working with a simple batch load process for a text file. I would like to add a timestamp for the insertion of the record in BigQuery. Is there a preferred pattern for adding a "insert date" for the PCollection?  I've seen a couple of different approaches but curious if there's a preferred pattern or best practice for this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice section on this within the Apache Beam documentation:

"An unbounded source provides a timestamp for each element. Depending on your unbounded source, you may need to configure how the timestamp is extracted from the raw data stream.

However, bounded sources (such as a file from TextIO) do not provide timestamps. If you need timestamps, you must add them to your PCollection’s elements."

There is also a nice java / python code example at:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-
pcollections-elements

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!  I did see this in the documentation and wanted to confirm I was interpreting it correctly.